# How to log only certain result/status codes with Squid?

Tags: logging, squid

By default Squid logs all access information including 'successes' and 'failures'. I'm interested in logging only 'failures'. In other words, I want to do something like log only Squid DENIED result codes, or, alternatively, don't log successful HTTP transactions. Regardless of how I define 'success' and 'failure', I need to be able to define more specifically what sort of access information Squid will write to the log file. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality with [ACLs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/), though there are some tricks to it.

The main trick is to make sure that you don't accidentally check binary connections for `http_status` codes.  Squid never sees status codes for binary connections and will throw a warning in `cache.log` for binary connection it sees if you mess this up.

Here is a sample config that will write all http success and redirections as well as all binary connections that finish opening a socket (we don't have success/failure visibility beyond that) to `success.log`, and all http failure codes and binary connections that fail to open a socket to `failure.log`.

```
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

# http status codes (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs)
acl success_codes http_status 100-199 # informational
acl success_codes http_status 200-299 # successful transactions
acl success_codes http_status 300-399 # redirection

acl failure_codes http_status 400-499 # client error
acl failure_codes http_status 500-599 # server error

acl success_hier hier_code HIER_DIRECT
acl failure_hier hier_code HIER_NONE

acl failure all-of CONNECT failure_hier
acl failure all-of !CONNECT failure_codes

acl success all-of CONNECT success_hier
acl success all-of !CONNECT success_codes

access_log stdio:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/success.log logformat=squid success
access_log stdio:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/failure.log logformat=squid failure
```

The problem with this config is that it disables the default log file and will not log anything that doesn't match one of those two ACLs.  Now, I'm pretty confident that I've written my ACLs well and that I've accounted for all possibilities, but this would still make me nervous, so you might want to add another log file just to catch anything that happens to miss both ACLs

```
access_log stdio:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/unknown.log logformat=squid !success !failure
```

Or you can just define `success` and set failure to `!success`

```
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

# http status codes (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs)
acl success_codes http_status 100-199 # informational
acl success_codes http_status 200-299 # successful transactions
acl success_codes http_status 300-399 # redirection

acl success_hier hier_code HIER_DIRECT
acl failure_hier hier_code HIER_NONE

acl success all-of CONNECT success_hier
acl success all-of !CONNECT success_codes

access_log stdio:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/success.log logformat=squid success
access_log stdio:/usr/local/squid/var/logs/failure.log logformat=squid !success
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am seeing an error on the "acl success_hier hier_code HIER_DIRECT" line. The reason for the error is likely because I am using Squid3 3.1.19. According to the Squid change log, there was a bug, "parsing hier_code acl fails," addressed in squid-3.2.2. So I probably need to upgrade to a more recent version of Squid, which I am unable to do at the moment. I'll try to reply back when I am able to carry out the upgrade.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't proxy SSL, or if you don't mind SSL successes going to your error log, you can just drop the `heir_code` and `all-of` bits, and use the `success_codes` ACL in your log lines

Comment: I upgraded to Squid3 3.3.8, and now the HIER_DIRECT directive seems to be parsing fine. However, now I am seeing an error at the line with the "all-of" directive. It seems that the all-of directive was introduced in Squid3 3.4!  Is there some alternative that can be used in place of all-of?

Comment: You may be able to find something in the [docs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/access_log/), but the only thing I can some up with is to log SSL to it's own file or to let it go to failures. (see my post from 9/27)

Comment: Please give me some more time to test this. I will reply back with my result later.

Comment: This answer works for me